# Can anyone suggest a paper similar to mass-produced movie posters?

Tags: print-design, print-production, posters, paper

I'm looking to print posters similar to the mass-produced movie posters. Is there a place online that sells 13"x19" or 11"x17" or similar sized paper that I can use for printing posters?

I can't seem to find any info on the subject.

Comment: What printing process? Silk Print? Ink-Jet? Lithography?

Comment: You can contact the paper houses directly. For instance, here's one that's still around: Lindenmeyr Munroe. BTW, 11x17 is a common size.

Comment: Check your printer user manual to see what types of coated paper you can print on. Some brands produce matt photo paper, which is specifically formulated for your printer. For example Canon makes matt photo paper which is specially formulated for their inkjet printers.

Answer (score 3):

The definition you are looking for is 'coated stock'.

This is regular paper which then has a layer of liquified clay, chalk & latex applied to it. This gives it the shiny surface I think you are looking for. [You can also get semi-gloss or matt surfaces, but regular 'coated' will be shiny unless you specify otherwise.] Coated stock will make images 'pop' better on the page; this is what magazines are printed on, as opposed to regular text books.

The downside is it is less absorbent.
The ink will sit on the surface more & not be absorbed into the body of the paper so well as uncoated. I am really not sure how it would behave on a domestic inkjet printer - perhaps using a photopaper setting would help.

I used to work in the print trade, but so long ago it was before inkjets were used for commercial printing, so I have no experience with those. I found this from Xerox on printing to coated stocks - https://digitalprinting.blogs.xerox.com/2016/09/27/digital-inkjet-printing-on-coated-stocks-is-now-possible/

One other thing to watch out for is that clay is heavier than wood, so if you usually look at your paper thicknesses from only the weight/gsm figure, a coated will be thinner than uncoated for any given paper weight of similar density. Use the calliper measurement to be certain… or ask for samples.
Magazines would generally be printed on anything from 80-130gsm, 'Art' posters maybe heavier, cheap cinema posters [those they put under glass outside the cinema] probably at the low end of that, 80gsm or even thinner.

If you're still not really sure which you need, talk to your stockist. It's their job to sell you what you need. They want you to come back for more, not be disappointed.

Comment: To print on coated stock on an inkjet, you would have to get a cartridge of photo ink, (which is tackier than the ink used on non-coated stock). On a printing press, the ink flow would have to be reduced, (so as to not lay too much ink down), and thinned down, (by reducing the water/ink ratio) to make it tackier. This will affect the drying time.